# Auto follow scroll bar in div

Tags: javascript, css

Basically, I've created some kind of **Autolog** which has a scrollable DIV using the CSS code below

```
.myClass {
position: relative;
padding: 39px 14px 14px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Basically, data is being placed inside this div dynamically using JQuery as shown below which is fetched from an external source

```
$.each(data.search, function (i, v) {
        $('.myClass').append('my content here');
});
```

The div is looks as simple as this

```
<div class="myClass">

</div>
```

What i want the div to do, is as the content is becoming `overflow` i want the scrollbar at the side to automatically scroll to the bottom to follow the **AutoLog** instead of having to manually keep scrolling the bar to the bottom yourself, I'm sure this can be acheived via **Javascript** but not sure how, if anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did something similar, where I had a "console" (a div) I was printing to and when it overflowed, you followed it down. here was my "println" function:

```
printLn: function(str, clss) {
    con.print(str, clss);
    $output.append('<br/>').animate({ scrollTop: $output.prop('scrollHeight') }, 1);
},
```

Basically update `scrollTop` to the new `scrollHeight`, which more or less says "scroll as far as the scroll height allows" so you "stick" to the bottom.

**EDIT**

For your situation doing something like:

```
$.each(data.search, function (i, v) {
        $div = $('.myClass');
        $div.append('my content here').animate({ scrollTop: $div.prop('scrollHeight') }, 1);
});
```

This sets the `scrollTop` property of your div to the max, so it will scroll to the bottom.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't even understand what you're trying to throw at me here, but thanks very much for taking your time to post this

Comment: @CurtisCrewe Edited with a specific example for your case

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script after appending content and it should work ..

```
$(".myClass").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".myClass").scrollHeight
}, 300);
```

Comment: $.each(data.search, function (i, v) {
        $('.myClass').append('my content here').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(".myClass").scrollHeight
        }, 300);
    });

Comment: that hasn't appeared to work, thanks for your contribution anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the number of pixels scrolled
var  intElemScrollTop = element.scrollTop;
intElemScrollTop is an integer corresponding to number of pixels that element's content has been scrolled upward.

// Set the number of pixels scrolled
element.scrollTop = intValue;
```

check the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop